# Use Cacti to Monitor HTTP Status Codes of Request Responses?

Tags: php, curl, monitoring, cacti

I have a proxy script that makes HTTP GET requests to other pages using cURL through PHP.

Is it possible to monitor what response codes are returned to those cURL requests, using Cacti? If not Cacti, possible with any similar monitoring system?

For example, I want a report that shows how many responses came in each status category, ie, with a 200, a 404, 500, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you CAN use Cacti to do such things.   You can graph just about anything with it.  http://docs.cacti.net/manual:087:3a_advanced_topics.1_data_input_methods#data_input_methods

It sounds though from your question that you want a monitoring and alerting solution,  not just a graphing solution.    For monitoring, alerting, and graphing (though the graphs are not nearly as attractive as rrdtool and cacti)  I like the opensource Hyperic product(http://www.hyperichq.com).    There is also Nagios, BigBrother and a host of other low cost / no cost options.